# Salvar dados de um arquivo .txt numa matriz

Tags: c

O algoritmo abaixo importa dados de um txt e salva num vetor. Tentei adaptar o código pra salvar numa matriz e não funciona.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int t[100],n,i;

void getArray ()
{

   char *token;
   char help [256];
   FILE *Inputfile;
   Inputfile = fopen("UPDATE.txt","r");
   fscanf(Inputfile,"%i",help);
   token = strtok(help,",");

 i=0;

  while (token != NULL)
  {
     t[i] = atoi(token);
     token = strtok(NULL,",");
     i++;
}
    n=i;
}

   void printArray ()
{ 
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  printf("%d",t[i]);
}
}
   main ()
{
   getArray ();
   printArray ();
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Olá

A diferença entre um vetor e uma matriz em C é sutil.

Um vetor é uma sequência de valores do mesmo tipo

Uma matriz é um vetor de vetores. Portanto, cada elemento do primeiro vetor é, em si, um vetor para, aí sim, os valores do tipo considerado.

Basicamente, o que mudaria no programa acima é o tratamento dos tokens para a matriz.

Primeiro deves declarar mais uma variável:

```
int t[100][10], n, i, j;  //n, i para linhas, j para colunas
```

Depois mude o `while` correspondentemente.

```
i=0; j=0;
while (token != NULL)
{
   t[i][j] = atoi(token);
   token = strtok(NULL,",");
   i++; j++;
   if(j == 10) j=0;
}
n=i;
```

Claro que isso é simplificado. O ideal aqui seria pegar as duas primeiras leituras do arquivo para serem o número de linhas e número de colunas. Aí o programador alocaria espaço suficiente na matriz (via VLA na pilha ou via malloc no heap) e faria o número correto de iterações.

Answer (score -3):

Sou novato em C, mas poderia lhe recomendar uma função para transformar seu vetor em matriz?
numero_de_dados seriam quantos dados você quer passar

```
int cont = 0; //contador

int cont2 = 0; //segundo contador

int cont3 = 0; //terceiro

for (cont=0; cont<numero_de_dados;cont++){
for (cont3=0; cont3<numero_de_colunas;cont3++){
for (cont2=0; cont2<numero_de_dados_por_linha;cont2++){
matriz[cont2][cont3] == vetor[cont];

}

}

}
```

Perdão eventuais erros de código, faz muito tempo que não programo.